# Developing Quiz App - Data Storage iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, offline

I am planning to develop a quiz app in iOS and doing it offline. I need to store 100s of questions and options in that app. How to store? How does core data comes in handy here? Is there any other good methods for this problem?

The app is meant to be **offline**.

Comment: A simple plist file will probably do; It is xml so it is easy to build from some other database you may have and you can simply load the whole thing into memory; Even hundreds of questions will only be a few megabytes at most, probably less

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use realm.io. It measures better than core data, its fast and simple to use. On https://realm.io there is lots of documentation.

I find realm much easier to set up and in generally to comprehend. It works nicely with SwiftJSON and hence in my view much easier to connect to backend.

Preloading core data can be quite cumbersome and to me it seems that core data still relies heavily on objective c.

On the other Core Data is made by Apple so it could be more stable solution on longer run (parse.com)

Comment: That's not a useful answer unless you include details about why Realm is good in this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SQLite database for saving Questions and Answers offline for your Quiz app. You can create tables in SQLite and save and fetch data from that using SQLite queries.